# Problems with Cx_freeze

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

If I'm actually asking you for help, it's because I spend many hours for nothing into trying to fix my problem:

I would like to compile my python script into .exe:
(I am using Python 32 bits 3.1.4 and pygame)

I have 4 files: *Class*.pyc, _Class_game.pyc, _ressources.pyc et main.py
and a folder @ressources with all images and songs

This is my scritp setup.py:

```
import cx_Freeze
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("main.py"), base = "Win32GUI"]
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Strike The square",
    version = "2.0",
    description = "Jeu Strike The Square, V2.1",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                           "include_files":   ["_Class_.pyc","_Class_game.pyc","_ressources.pyc"]}},
    executables = executables

)
```

This create a folder "exe.xin32-3.1" with python (compiled) and my game

Next, I use inno setup to build the installer and add the folder @ressources

On my computer, It works very well, but when one of my friend wants to play (he hasn't python and pygame), the game creates this error:
[Error][1]

Then...I think this error comes from windows' ressources but I don't know how can I fix it...
The option (in setup.py):

```
include_msvcr = True
```

Doesn't work...

Thanks for your answer and excuse my english...

Hawk_Eyes

PS: this my game imports

```
try:
    import pygame,time, ctypes
    from random import randint
    from pygame.locals import *
    from math import sqrt 
    from _ressources import Shared
except ImportError as e:
    print("Erreur du chargement du module: {0}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help but this is a copy of my setup file, i have used this to compile Pygame, Pubnub and various things. notice i don't include the files i want to include. The setup auto finds the files needed.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

exe = Executable(
    script = r"launcher.py",
    base = 'Win32GUI',
    icon = None,
    targetName = "launcher.exe"
    )

setup(
    version = "0.1",
    description = "launcher",
    author = "Joshua Nixon",
    name = "launcher",
    executables = [exe]
    )

$ cd path/to/files
$ python file.py build
```

**EDIT**

I recently found you could create .MSI files using cx_freeze which are very nice for distributing. IF the program uses images then (because you cannot bundle images with the MSI (that i know of) you create a little function which downloads them on launch from imgur or some place))

setup.py for MSI

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

company_name = "JoshuaNixon"
product_name = "Test"

bdist_msi_options = {
    'add_to_path': False,
    'initial_target_dir': r'[ProgramFilesFolder]\%s' % (company_name),
    }

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
else:
    base = None

exe = Executable(script='launcher.py',
                 base=base,
                 icon="mushroom.ico",
                )

setup(name=product_name,
      version='1.0.0',
      description='blah',
      executables=[exe],
      options={'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options})

$ cd path/to/files
$ python file.py bdist_msi
```

Comment: This is my log when i build game, i think there is error...:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9GkmPh0aqlGamlvZm1MOURrZWc

Comment: It looks fine to me. The exe or MSI will be in your dist/build folder in Your Python folder. The files you want to compile must be in your Python folder when you do it.

Comment: hum... wich python and pygame and cx_freeze version do you use ?

Comment: Python34 and cx_Freeze-4.3.4

Comment: yeah but pygame doesn't work on python 3.4 ... So how can I use pygame ?

Comment: Why doesn't it? I use pygame and Python 3.4. ```pip install pygame```  that's it

Comment: Hum... look here : http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
There's no pygame for 3.4... And I'am working on Windows... does pip work on Windows ?

Comment: Nice mate! About time!