# Converting Python 3.6 script to .exe?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I would like to convert a .py file to an .exe. I am using Python 3.6. I already tried py2exe and PyInstaller but they don't seem to work properly with Python 3.6.

Here is the [traceback from PyInstaller](https://%70astebin.com/E0thBnKn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's try Pyinstaller first.

```
$ pyinstaller script.py --onefile
```

This will generate a script.spec file
in the spec file you can remove the console, debug mode etc

```
$ pyinstaller script.py
```

EDIT: [Py3.6 isn't supported](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2329)

If this doesn't work then we can try [cx_freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43429686/4180176),

Comment: Didn't work. It gave me "IndexError: tuple index out of range" in the cmd

Comment: Send the full traceback.

Comment: The full traceback is hundreds of lines long. It's too much for a normal comment

Comment: We just want error traceback. what tuple? what line? what module?

Comment: Yeah, and the traceback is, as said, a few hundreds of lines long. I would love to send the whole traceback but it's not possible with my 600 characters limitation, it exceeds that by about 3000 characters. I can't really read what line and what module, the traceback talks about several modules and lines

Comment: pastebin.com...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't think about that. https://pastebin.com/E0thBnKn

Comment: so 3.6 isn't supported (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2329)

Comment: Do you need 3.6 or can you drop to 3.4?

Comment: i edited my answer

Comment: I could, yes. Thanks for the answer, you helped me a lot