# Pyinstaller for Python 3.6 tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, exe, pyinstaller

I am currently trying to convert a .py file to a .exe file using pyinstaller. When i try and do so in the cmd, i get an error

```
Index Error: tuple index out of range
```

I am not sure how to fix it, I have looked around but the posts seems to be 6+ months regarding this topic

Comment: I think pyinstaller is not yet developed completely for python 3.6.Try it with python 3.5

Comment: It might be helpful if you showed us some code of how you're using tuples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Python 3.6 script to .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535920/converting-python-3-6-script-to-exe)

Comment: I've had success building executable for Python 3.6 using the development branch of PyInstaller, so you could give that a try.